# Create item in XML infopath form library

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, csom

I have infopath form library. I have excel file which has some data. I want to create item in infopath form reading the excel values using CSOM.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below code:

```
public static void ChangeFields()
{
    //Open SharePoint site
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://<SharePoint_Site_URL>"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            //Get handle for forms library
            SPList formsLib = web.Lists["FormsLib"];

            if (formsLib != null)
            {
                foreach (SPListItem item in formsLib.Items)
                {
                    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

                    //Open XML file and load it into XML document
                    using (Stream s = item.File.OpenBinaryStream())
                    {
                        xml.Load(s);
                    }

                    //Do your stuff with xml here. This is just an example of setting a boolean field to false.
                    XmlNodeList nodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("my:SomeBooleanField");
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                        node.InnerText = "0";
                    }

                    //Get binary data for new XML
                    byte[] xmlData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml);

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlData))
                    {
                        //Write data to SharePoint XML file
                        item.File.SaveBinary(ms);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source:

[Programmatically Edit Infopath Form Fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968809/programmatically-edit-infopath-form-fields)

Read Excel file using C# coding:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            Excel.Range range ;

            string str;
            int rCnt ;
            int cCnt ;
            int rw = 0;
            int cl = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"d:\csharp-Excel.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            rw = range.Rows.Count;
            cl = range.Columns.Count;


            for (rCnt = 1; rCnt  < = rw; rCnt++)
            {
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt  < = cl; cCnt++)
                {
                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                    MessageBox.Show(str);
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

        }
```

Source:

[How to read an Excel file using C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm)